# how to remove ♥ (or â™¥) from a string in php?

Tags: php, string, replace

this text block represents the original external source that is a variable:

```
// the following characters are not-consistent 
text here
// the following characters are consistent
♥ text1
♥ text2
♥ text3
// the following characters are consistent
some more text here
```

i want to remove everything except for `"text here"` and i have to do this in 'parts' as other text may be present (ie i can't just remove everything after `"text here"`).

i can remove `"some more text here"` but am having trouble trying to target and remove the lines beginning with ♥ (or â™¥ as they are currently being stored in the database).

so these are my variables

```
// this is the original external source

$part_one = $external_source; 

// this is the variable that is not working yet

$part_one_a = ;

// this replaces "some more text here" with nothing

$part_one_b = str_replace("some more text here", " ", $part_one);

// this concatenates the variables $part_one_a and $part_one_b

$final = $part_one_a . $part_one_b;
```

thank you.

**update**

to be more specific i need a way to remove text such as this:

```
♥ link_one:  http://link_one_here.com/
♥ link_two:  http://link_two_here.com/
♥ link_three:  http://link_three_here.com/
```

**update two**

i've managed to remove all unwanted items with str_replace on an array.

the only thing i cannot target and therefore remove is the ♥.

i have tried targeting it with:

- `â™¥` (this is the value that is currently being stored in the
  database)
- `&acirc;™&yen;` (after i applied a htmlentities to the string)

and no luck - the ♥ is still being displayed.  if anyone can tell me how i can target ♥ it would be much appreciated and this question would be resolved.

thank you.

Comment: You may want to skip every non-ASCII unicode char, but that might be too strong....

Comment: Your description seems to be contradictory: you say that you "want to remove everything except for `text here`", but that there might also be other text you need to keep?  How do you determine if some particular text needs to be kept or discarded?

Comment: in the example above i want to remove all parts except for `text here`, there may however be other elements present in this variable (as it is an external and non-consistent source) and so that is why i have to be able to target each element in the example above and remove it (so that the other text that may be there still displays).  i can successfully remove all elements except for the lines that start with ♥ (or â™¥ as they are currently being stored in the database).  so my question is how to remove these lines.

Comment: set the character set to utf-8 ?

Comment: thank you for your reply @Chris, could you please provide more information on how to do this, on both the form page that is grabbing the data and the page that is displaying the data from the database i have `<meta charset="UTF-8" /> ` in the head area, searching for `set the character set to utf-8 php` lead me in a few directions at once, any clarification appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Add this to the top of the page.. <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?> might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was:

1. Do a [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on an array to target and remove specific portions of text.
2. Create a regex and define acceptable values.
3. Do a [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on non-acceptable values.

this resulted in all the desired values being shown without instances of non-acceptable characters.

the code for the last two steps is below:

```
// this is the original external source

$part_one = $external_source; 

// create a regex

$regex
= '~'
. '['
. '^'
. 'A-Z'
. '0-9'
. ' '
. '!_:/,.#$-'
. ']'
. '~'
. 'i'
;

// clean the string

$part_one_cleaned = preg_replace($regex, NULL, $part_one);
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly you need the all `text here` which is  before ♥  you can use `strpos`

```
$stopper = '♥';
$string = 'text here

♥ text1
♥ text2
♥ text3

some more text here' ;
$final = trim(substr($string,0,strpos($string, $stopper)));
var_dump($final);
```

Output

```
string 'text here' (length=9)
```

Please note that your `$stopper` can also be `\n` new line

Comment: thank you very much for this suggestion, however i need to remove elements in a specifically targeted fashion as additional text may be present before or after the lines beginning with ♥ which also need to be included.  i think the main issue is trying to target the lines beginning with ♥ as my code and text editors turn that symbol into a questions mark `?` and if i use `â™¥` the content is not removed.

Comment: You said you wanted `text here` not `text1` , `text2` , `text3` ...... it showing `?` because of charset settings